# Google Maps: set StyledMapType with Terrain

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Problem:** I want to use a google maps v3 terrain map with own styles as an own mapType.

I started with this code:

```
var mapOptions = {
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  styles: styles
};
```

It shows my terrain with my own styles. Thats okay!
Now, i want too add this to the mapTypeIds

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: "NSW"
}); 

var mapOptions = {
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'map_style']
  }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(map_id[0],
    mapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

The problem is, google maps uses "ROADMAP" for the "StyledMapType" and i've no idea how to change this to "TERRAIN". Is that even possible?

**Update:**

[image: A Screenshot of the "google.maps.StyledMapType"]

As you can see, "roadmap" is default. In the main.js from the google maps api there is the line:

```
k=c.baseMapTypeId||"roadmap"
```

So, what is the baseMapTypeId? The one, which i set in the mapOptions like:

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
```

???

May, this helps to solve my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var styles = [{
    "stylers": [{
        "saturation": -100
    }]
}];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: "Name of your style"
});

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 10
});

map.mapTypes.set('NSW', styledMap);

var mapTypeControlOptions = {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'NSW']
    }
};

map.setOptions(mapTypeControlOptions);
```

Note that the name of your `StyledMapType` is the name that will be displayed on the map, and the `id` of your `MapStyle` that you declare with the `set` method is what you need to use to reference your map style.

Hope this helps!

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8tb8udm3/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

If you want to apply custom styles over the `TERRAIN` map style, you could do it by setting the `styles` of the current map type. You can add a custom control to your map to handle the toggling.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/faubsg0n/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the terrain view, which you have styled. Its roadmap. If you set your saturation to 0 in your fiddle, you will see the difference between terrain and your styledMap.

Comment: Right. What's the final goal? You want to be able to set your own style *above* the TERRAIN map with your own button?

Comment: Yes, but with my own "StyledMapType".

Comment: I don't think you can. Why would you need your own map type? See my edit above and let me know if that would be ok.

Comment: It is possible to style the terrain, without a own mapstyle. But i want to switch between my styled terrain and the roadmap. Btw. i updated my question above. some more information.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to set a different base map for StyledMapType.**

Note the second argument. You've actually figured this out by yourself, based on your screenshot and updated comment.

```
new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { baseMapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN })
```